# Keep a dropdown list highlighted after a post back in .net aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 7 dropdown lists within my page , following a post back from dropdown list 1 I want this to still be highlighted when the page reloads so that I have the ability to tab to the next dropdown list

I have tried smart navigation but this did not work. I'm using framework 3

Any guidance would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `focus()` method

For example in code-behind:

```
DropDownList1.Focus();
```

This will give focus to DropDownList1

Alternatively you can use

```
Page.SetFocus("IdOfControl");
```

You will need to store the ID of the control in either a session or querystring so you can access it after postback so you know which control to give focus to.

Comment: Thanks, if I store the id of the control to I use Page.Setfocus in the onpage load event ?

Comment: @RhysWillis You should be able to use either one. FYI if the control is not in view on the page it won't scroll down unless you maintain scroll position. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback%28v=vs.85%29.aspx